# PhoneGap - Multiple WebViews

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

I have read almost all the posts relating this topic - but nowhere i could find complete code/appropriate answer

I am trying to adding two PhoneGap WebViews in an iPhone PhoneGap app.

Below is the code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    self.cleaver1 = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.cleaver2 = [[[MainViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

    self.cleaver1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
    self.cleaver2.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 420);

    self.cleaver1.wwwFolderName = @"www";
    self.cleaver1.startPage = @"navigation.html";
    self.cleaver2.wwwFolderName = @"www";
    self.cleaver2.startPage = @"mail.html";

    TestViewController *vc = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];

    [vc.view addSubview:self.cleaver1.view];
    [vc.view addSubview:self.cleaver2.view];

    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Both, webviews are loading "index.html", its not working as desire.

Please suggest me, whether PhoneGap supports Multiple WebViews?